# MEF problem with import

Tags: wpf, mef

I have problem with import shell-view-model to view-model class, I use MEF.

Shell-view-model :

```
namespace Spirit.ViewModels
{
    using Caliburn.Micro;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

    public interface IShellViewModel
    {
        void ShowLogOnView();
        void ShowMessengerView();
    }

    [Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>, IShellViewModel
    {
        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            ShowLogOnView();
        }

        public void ShowLogOnView()
        {
            ActivateItem(new LogOnViewModel());
        }

        public void ShowMessengerView()
        {
            ActivateItem(new LogOnViewModel());
        }
    }

}
```

I need this class import in view-model class:

```
[Export]
public class LogOnViewModel : Screen, IDataErrorInfo
{

    [Import]
    private IShellViewModel _shellViewModel;


    public void LogOn(string nick, string password)
    {
        IMessengerViewModel vm = IoC.Get<MessengerViewModel>();
        _shellViewModel.ShowMessengerView();
    }
}
```

Problem is after initialize is variable _shellViewModel null.

My bootstraper look like this:

```
  public class MefBootStrapper : Bootstrapper<IShellViewModel>
  {

  }
```

**MY SOLUTION:**

I create interface assembly and refer this assembly in external service dll and also in wpf app.

In bootstraper I load this assembly with reflection:

```
    var catalog =
    new AggregateCatalog(
        AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>());

catalog.Catalogs.Add(
    new AssemblyCatalog(string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"\Pokec_Toolkit.dll")));

_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

Than I create conductor class:

```
public interface IShellViewModel
{
    void ShowLogOnView();
    void ShowMessengerView();
}

[Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>, IShellViewModel
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        ShowLogOnView();
    }

    public void ShowLogOnView()
    {
        ActivateItem(IoC.Get<LogOnViewModel>());
    }

    public void ShowMessengerView()
    {
        ActivateItem(IoC.Get<MessengerViewModel>());
    }
}
```

And in view-model I have this:

```
  [Export]
    public class LogOnViewModel : Screen, IDataErrorInfo, ILogOnViewModel
    {

        [Import]
        private IShellViewModel _shellViewModel;

        [Import]
        private IPokecConnection _pokecConn;

//this method is bind on event click of button
        public void LogOn(string nick, string password)
        {
            //SHOW NEW WIEW
           _shellViewModel.ShowMessengerView();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your bootstrapper code is empty.  You probably need to add code somewhere to start the composition.

Comment: No, I omited logic in Boostraper for simplification. Solution is on the top.

Comment: Where are you doing the ComposeParts?